# How to make the text do not fall behind the layer without using the absolute property?

Tags: html, css

How to make the text do not fall behind the layer without using the absolute property?

HTML

```css
.select-item { 
  width: 35px;
  height: 34px;
  border: none; 
  font-size: 12pt;
  height: 34px;
  font-color: white;
  color:#6083bc;
  text-align:  center;
  padding-top:5px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;   
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #eaf2ff);   
  cursor:pointer;
}
#block {
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 10px;
  position:relative;
  top: 34px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;  
  -webkit-transition: All .2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: All .2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: All .2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: All .2s ease-out;
  transition: All .2s ease-out; 
}
#toggle-1 {
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
} 
#toggle-1:checked ~ #block {
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;   
}
div {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    <label class="select-item boxinside arrow" for="toggle-1" style="display:block;">+      </label> 
    <input id="toggle-1" type="checkbox">
    <div id="block">
      text in div text in div text in div text in div
    </div>
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </div>
```

Please see my page on jsFiddle :
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsman82/qmmo8y98/3/)

Comment: You should post your code here aswell just incase someone in the futur search for the same thing and fiddle doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This Fix Your Problem

HTML

```
<div>

<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
<div id="block">This Is Dropdown</div>

Text 1
<label class="select-item boxinside arrow"  style="display:block;" for="toggle-1">+</label>

Text 2

</div>
```

CSS

```
.select-item {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background: #222;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
#block {
    background: green;
    width: 300px;
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 100px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: All .2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: All .2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: All .2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: All .2s ease-out;
    transition: All .2s ease-out;
}
#toggle-1 {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
#toggle-1:checked~#block {
    background: red;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px
}
div {
    width: 300px;
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7yLoo3Lw/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your attention to my question! But I need the text to stay in place, ie the drop-down layer should be above the text.

Comment: Here's how I needed https://jsfiddle.net/jsman82/qmmo8y98/65/, but I want to be able to make a red block for example under the button.